# My Playstation 2 controller to USB adapter shows up as a HID game controller, but not as a Windows game controller

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, game-controller

I'm running Windows 7 x64.
I just picked up a PS2 to USB adapter, downloaded the drivers from their website, and became stumped. It isn't detected as a gamepad, yet I can use it in games that utilize one (L4D2, TF2, Half-Life, etc.)
It shows up (twice) in Device Manager as "HID-compliant game controller," yet going into "Game Controllers Settings" from control panel shows 0 installed controllers.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you verify the driver is Windows 7 and 64-bit compatible? Some devices are not recognized properly when plugged into to the front panel. If it is connected to the front panel, try the back (MB) slot.

Comment: @CharlieRB yep. Doesn't work on any port, and is windows 7 64 bit compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My adapter appeared to windows as a DirectInput game controller! Source games like L4D2 and TF2 ( which has since removed DirectInput support) work with DirectInput, but the Game Controllers settings built into Windows only show XboxInput game controllers.