# Playstation 2 Buzz Controller does not work on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, game-controller, hid, playstation

I tried installing the [USB game controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz!#Buzz.21_buzzers) for the Playstation 2 version of the quiz-game "Buzz!" on my Windows 10 computer. While this (pretty simple) controller works well on Linux and (as far as I can remember) on older Windows versions.

Unfortunately, when I plug the controller in, the driver Windows automatically installs has the status "Driver error" in Settings/Connected devices. The driver it installs is called "Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1". Searching for this driver name didn't bring up anything useful for me.

In the device manager it shows a "Standard USB Hub" with an error: "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)".

My wish is, that the controller gets recognized as a gamepad or generic hid-controller so I can use the input data. I wouldn't mind translating the byte-input myself.

Comment: Looks like a common problem with [Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/480600/my-playstation-2-controller-to-usb-adapter-shows-up-as-a-hid-game-controller-bu?rq=1) also

Comment: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) can now analyze USB traffic on at least some types of hubs. You might want to give that a shot to see what's going on here.

Comment: @bwDraco I didn't need it in the end, but that seems to be a cool tool to check out. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution shortly after posting the question:

In the device manager select the broken "Standard USB Hub" and open the properties for it. Select "Update Driver", "Browse my computer for driver software", "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer". There select "USB Input Device" and click OK.

The device "Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1" installs now properly and is usable.

Comment: Tipp works for Windows 7 Pro 32bit as well

Comment: I needed to change "HID-compliant game controller" to "HID-compliant device"

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly for me!

Comment: Thanks, it works on Windows 11 too ;)